# Elongated Spacing with Title

Tags: revtex

I am writing a paper with the revtex4 style and there is an elongated spacing with the affiliation environment. The spacing with the supervisor's name is elongated between "Dr." and "John". Is there a way that I can shorten the spacing?

```
\documentclass[aps,prb,twocolumn,groupedaddress,nofootinbib,floatfix]{revtex4}

\begin{document}

\title{Title
}

\author{Name}
\affiliation{%
University Name\\
Another University Name\\
Supervisor: Dr. John Smith
}

\date{\today}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There's a few things you can do. Probably simplest would be to use a fixed amount of space (backslash comma, e.g.), like so: `Dr.\,John Smith`. I am afraid the kerning remains rather ugly, though.

Comment: When a period signals an abbreviation and follows a lowercase letter, the standard way to input it is with `\@`: `Dr.\@ John Smith` Alternatively `Dr.\ John Smith`